# Histogram on elements of a 2D matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am wondering if there is any build in function or an easy way to plot a histogram of elements of a `2d array`.

For example, if `A=rand(100,1)`, then `A` is an `1D array`, and `hist(A)` can do the histogram.

However, what if `A=rand(100,100)`, and I would like to make a histogram on elements of `A`, just like treating each element in `A` as an element on a `1D array`. Is there a easy way to do so?

Answer (score 13):

You just have to reshape `A` into a vector, then you can use `hist` as usual:

```
hist(A(:))
```

Comment: I like MATLAB's simple column vectorization, `A(:)` because it always seems like the array is smiling, whichever direction you look at it :)

Answer (score 2):

This command will do what you want:

```
hist(reshape(A, prod(size(A)), 1))
```

What it does is create a vector out of the matrix A by reshaping it into a matrix with one column and a number of rows equal to the number of elements of A:

```
prod(size(A)) = number_of_columns(A) * number_of_rows(A)
```

Or the short way:

```
hist(A(:))
```

This takes every element of A in sequence and thus also generates a vector.

Comment: `A(:)` as in Jonas' answer does the same as the long reshape command.