# Visualise histogram movement in blender

Tags: histogram, blender

I have a set of 2D arrays (30x30) each 2d array gives rise to a histogram. I can visualise each of them with Matlab (see here: [Histogram on elements of a 2D matrix on Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568516/histogram-on-elements-of-a-2d-matrix-on-matlab)). However, I would like to see the histogram moving in blender. I could now create a keyframe with 900 boxes by hand and justify the height of each indivdualy but this would take a long time. Also, I have to justify the height of all 900 boxes per keyframe, which takes clearly too much time.

Is there a smart way how to quickly get an histogram movement in blender from a set of 2D arrays?

Answer (score 0):

There exists an addon to import csv data and use the values for F-Curves (http://sourceforge.net/projects/csv-fc-importer/) but in only creates F-Curves for one object, so you would have to manualy import 900 csv files.

In your case i would create the boxes with ordered names (i.e. box.0.0 to box.29.29) and write the script myself. If you are familiar with python, you can find an excelent tutorial here: http://blendersushi.blogspot.de/2012/12/python-importing-and-visualizing-data.html